# Trying to understand the regex. Need Help in understanding the regex

Tags: c#, regex

I was trying to understand the following regex

```
^(?!\s)(?!.*\s\s)[ A-Za-z0-9'-]{1,35}(?<!\s)$
```

Here I understood,

`^(?!\s)` - (lookahead) means will not match if there is a leading space.

`[ A-Za-z0-9'-]{1,35}` - will allow A to Z, a to z, 0 to 9, (space), ' and -.

`(?<!\s)$` - means will not match if there is a trailing space.

I am unable to understand what this sub-expression is doing?

```
(?!.*\s\s)
```

Comment: [`(?!.*\s\s)`](https://regex101.com/r/lE2nZ5/1) Check right top corner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(?!.*\s\s)
```

means that in the string there should not be `2` adjacent spaces.

`.*` will scan the string.
`\s\s` will look for adjacent spaces.`?!` is negative lookahead so it will break when it finds such a string.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/eB8xU8/4

Comment: I did a sample application which takes regex and the subject string. for the given input "(?!.*\s\s)" "Abc  Def" it is returning true. Note that there are 2 spaces between "Abc" and "Def".

Comment: @NJMR u need to use `^(?!.*\s\s).*$`

Comment: Taking the above example which is "Abc  Def" (there are 2 spaces). My question is .* will consume the first space and you are left with only single space. Then the pattern should match the subject. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @NJMR .* will consume but then backtracks as it has to match \s\s ....so it will leave d two so that d match can happen

Answer (score -1):

I think there is no effect for this lookup.. It will return always true because here you are using greedy search. 
It should be
**(?!.*?\s\s)**: which means no two spaces continuous..

**.***  this is for match everything situation with out looking here and there
**.* ?**  this makes this as a lazy operator and consider situation written at the right side of  **.*?**

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have tried the regex for the following input. "Abc   Def". The regex returns false. There are 3 spaces between "Abc" and "Def"

Comment: @NJMR Tell me an exact string you want to match so that i can help you out.. The regular expression written above will fail for sure.. as it is not correct..

Comment: I dont want to match any string which had leading, trailing and adjacent spaces. The "^(?!\s)(?!.*\s\s)[ A-Za-z0-9'-]{1,35}(?<!\s)$ " is perfectly working fine for me. I want to understand (?!.*\s\s) how it is blocking adjacent spaces.

Comment: @NJMR see if you use this .* it means match all without caring any thing.. and if you are using .*?\s\s it means match all but after checking the condition given at the right which is \s\s and (?!.*?\s\s) this whole means look ahead with and return false if it contains two times \s\s.... if you want to check it for more than two spaces use this (?!.*?\s{1,})... for referrence use this ... http://www.regexr.com

Comment: This is incorrect.`.*` is greedy but it allows regex engine to backtrack.So this will work though `.*?` will be more efficient in some cases.

Comment: @vks just for understanding i was trying to explain in that way.... if you look into my post i said .* is greedy.. and .*? makes is lazy

Comment: `there is no effect for this lookup` is incorrect

Comment: @vks Got it.. That was by mistake..